# reconnect to disconnected putty session or connect to idle session in linux

Tags: linux, putty, session, connectivity

I need to reconnecting the putty session, I will tell you one example,
I'm installing the python manually in my centos os machine, while I run command make, phyton is compiling to makefile suddenly I lost putty connection and putty session is disconnected, which I reconnect and check terminal and run the command who, I can see there are 2 sessions connected and 1 is idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session is dead, and the SSH server just hasn't timed out yet (default timeouts are insanely high, as they assume a very unreliable network).  As a general rule, there's not any way you can directly connect to a disconnected SSH session, just like there's no way to connect to and take-over a session running on a different virtual terminal.

For future usage though, I would suggest looking into the programs `screen` and/or `tmux` (not sure which of the two is packaged on CentOS, but if you have both as an option, I would personally recommend `screen`).  Both programs are primarily designed for quickly switching between multiple shells started from a single remote session (in essence, they replicate virtual terminal functionality, but with different key bindings), but they have another rather useful feature: you can disconnect from a screen or tmux instance, keep it running, and reconnect later.  By starting a screen (or tmux) session immediately after you log in over SSH with PuTTY, you can then reconnect to that session if the connection gets dropped.